# doubt in file path

Tags: java, file-io

i tried a program comparing C:\Program Files and C://Program Files i checked with compareTo()==0 it comes they are equal. But i doubt if there is any difference between //&\ 
 Is there any difference? what is the difference between c:/program files and //?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean ` \\ ` and ` / `?

Comment: i typed \\ only its not coming as i typed. I what to know the difference if any b/w // & \\

Comment: Is your question about filesystem or about Java string literals?

Comment: well, Skaffman is trying to correct your question but you keep changing it back. It’s absolutely not clear what you really mean, but I suspect Skaffman’s edit was right so please stop reverting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference, at least in Sun's implementation. The `Win32FileSystem` normalizes paths by converting slashes and removing duplicate slashes.

If you want to be 100% portable, use `File.separator`

Answer (score 1):

The separator between path components depends on operating system. Java represents file path independently of operating system and that causes equality of values considered.
Conversion to native representation is done on lower level (as Bozho pointed out), and you should not worry about that. Nevertheless I'd recommend using "/" as separator, as it is more common OS-wise.

Comment: Don't hard-code "/", use `File.separator` or `System.getProperty("file.separator")`.

Comment: "conversion"+File.separator+"is"+File.separator+"more""+File.separator+"convinient"

Comment: and there is java.net.URL / File.toURL()